# How to clone a CharArrayWriter?

Tags: java, clone

In Java 1.5, how can I clone an instance of java.io.CharArrayWriter?

```
CharArrayWriter x = new CharArrayWriter(200);
x.write("foo bar bob");

CharArrayWriter y = x.clone();   //  Object.clone() is not visible!!
```

Thanks,
mobiGeek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no clone method, but you can use `writeTo` method.

```
CharArrayWriter copy = new CharArrayWriter(x.size());
x.writeTo(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CharArrayWriter` is not cloneable.  Depending on your actual requirement you can do similar with:

```
CharArrayWriter y = new CharArrayWriter();
y.write( x.toCharArray() );
```

Which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: writeTo() is a better solution as it avoids an extra array copy.

Comment: False.  CharArrayWriter extends Writer which has a write(char[]) method.  Check the docs... and anyone else who voted me down on that. ;)